# SSRS 2012 Report Page Breaks

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.  I currently have a report with 5 sub sections of data, each surrounded with a Rectangle.

I am wanting each sub section to appear on a new page and then be able to export to Excel and each section to appear on a new Tab.

I set Page Break / Break Location in each Rectangle to "Start" and label the PageName to what I want to call the Tab.  When I run the report the 4 subsections show correctly but I am left with a blank page before I get the 5 section, but when I export it to Excel it appears correctly.

What I want is 5 pages in the report for each section and when exporting I want 5 tabs, can someone tell me where I am going wrong with setting the pagebreaks if that is indeed what I am doing incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have set the page breaks to the same value on each rectangle?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the response and 110%, I have gone through a number of times to check and made sure that the report is pulling fresh each time i.e. not cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are successfully exporting to Excel, but not the report viewer, this suggests your report and page sizes are not correctly set up on your 4th subsection.

When you have report elements that are slightly too large for your report page, the parts that 'overhang' will generate a new page of just the part that overhangs.  This is often a very small amount of white space, so it looks like the page is completely blank.  When you are exporting to formats such as excel, this does not matter so you correctly see the page breaks as new sheets.

To check whether this is the case, add borders and fills of different colours to all your rectangles and then run the report.  On your 4th 'blank' page, if you see any colours or borders you will know which rectangle or report element is growing beyond its page.

Comment: Hi iamdave, thanks for the reply, I did as you suggested and colour coded each of my rectangles to see if anything goes on to the extra page and nothing at all shows, just white space and the colours I have used you wouldn't miss if they were bleeding over :)

Comment: @PJD  What happens if you add a background colour to the report body?

Comment: Just having another look and though I dont have much data moving out to the right, there is a lot to scroll down through, could this be causing the issue??  If this was the case I would of expected to see some of the colour that I set the rectangle to, to bleed over on to the blank page.

Comment: @PJD  Will depend on how large you have set your page size to be and how large your individual report pages end up after render.

Comment: I have set the report body to grey and all the other pages show a glimmer of the grey which I expected but the blank page is still showing completely blank, do you think this is down to the default page width as you mentioned before?

Comment: @PJD  Experiment and find out.  Make it larger and smaller and see what happens

Comment: Hi iamdave, thanks for all the help, when I increased the Properties/Position/Size/Height it now all fits and I have left extra space to allow this report to grow. Help was appreciated.

Comment: @PJD  Glad you got it sorted :)